# Trying to add a Carriage return in a XML code

Tags: xml

Trying ( tried both `&#xD` `&#xA` ) to add carriage return before `<gadget> and after</gadget>`. ( XML code )

But I'm getting an error message :

> Schema validation failed at line 40 and column 35 with
>   message:cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'gadgets' cannot have character
>   [children], because the type's content type is element-only.

```
 &#xD<gadget>https://localhost:8444/cuic/gadget/LiveData/LiveDataGadget.jsp?gadgetHeight=420&viewId=5D411E8A10000140000000230A4E5E6B&filterId=AgentStateDetailStats.agentID=loginId</gadget>&#xD
```

Comment: XML does use same special characters as htlm.  See wsiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: Here, I tried with only hitting the enter key and tried to save the code and it worked.

Comment: See duplicate link.  Also, you do realize that character entities ( `&#xD;` and  `&#xA;`) must end with a semicolon, right?

Comment: I am not a coder here but a Network Collboration Engineer, as fix to a problem one of my server had these changes to be made. Actually did try with that as well. Same error message shows up.